# Check each column in orderly way if a specified value is present

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table have 3 columns namely:

- Actual Key
- Confirmed Key
- Present Key

I am trying to get or query the table with the condition that if "X" value is present or is the value of any of those columns but in a hierarchical order, then return those data.

It is identified in this order:

1.Actual Key

2.Confirmed Key

3.Present Key

---

Example:

**Checking 1:** If X is present ONLY in Actual Key column then return that row. Else, proceed to checking # 2

**Checking 2:** If X is present ONLY in Confirmed Key column then return that row. Else, proceed to checking # 3

**Checking 3:** If X is present ONLY in Present Key column then return that row. Else, proceed to checking # 4

**Checking 4:** If X is not present in ANY of those 3 columns then return no data

I am trying to use SQL CASE Statements (https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)  but I am not quite sure how to work with it.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please add sample data and your desired output in table format

Comment: And its a `case` *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Where is your final `else`: if `X` is present in two or more columns then ...?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is something like this.

```
WHERE
(ActualKey = x and ConfirmedKey != x and PresentKey != x) or 
(ActualKey != x and ConfirmedKey = x and PresentKey != x) or 
(ActualKey != x and ConfirmedKey != x and PresentKey = x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for COALESCE Clause.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(Actualkey char(1), confirmedkey char(1), presentkey char(1))

insert into @table
values ('x',null,null), (null,'x',null),(null,null,'x'),(null,null,null)

SELECT * FROM @table where coalesce(actualkey, confirmedkey, presentkey) = 'x'
```

| Actualkey | confirmedkey | presentkey |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | x | NULL |
| NULL | NULL | x |

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `select top` with `order by`:

```
select top (1) t.*
from t
where @x in (ActualKey, ConfirmedKey, PresentKey)
order by (case when @x = ActualKey then 1
               when @x = ConfirmedKey then 2
               when @x = PresentKey then 3
          end);
```